# Spot the ball game, zooming problems, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a spot the ball game, so it will (eventually) be an image of a player kicking a ball but the ball has been removed and the player needs to click where the ball should be.

The first version went well and works.

http://enjoythespace.com/sites/game/test.html

But what I need to add is some sort of zooming so you can see more accurately where you are clicking. I been playing around and have come up with this

http://enjoythespace.com/sites/v2/demo.html

But once you click it looks great when zoomed in but when you go back to the image its way off.

I think its todo with how the image is setup, the #webpage is half the original size of the image and the #retina uses the full size of the image.

Any help?

Comment: The center of the spyglass is not centered directly on top of the pixel of the picture underneath it. e.g. if you pick the center of the image it works fine, but try to pick the top left "switch to Global edition" - you can't as it never goes under the spyglass center.

Comment: So what is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do? Im not sure what switch to Global edition means?

Comment: "switch to Global edition" is the text on a peach colored background at the top left of your sample image.  As for what to do, I would try to adjust the logic used on the page to ensure the zoom area is centered exactly above the pixel you are zooming in on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you aren't setting the retina backgroundPosition correctly.

This code works (I added a zoom variable to make it clear how changing the zoom would change the calculation, but it would need other changes too):

```
/*  Moving the retina div with the mouse
    (and scrolling the background) */
zoom = 2.0;
retina.css({
    left        : left - sizes.retina.width/2,
    top     : top - sizes.retina.height/2,
    backgroundPosition : ""+(-zoom*left+sizes.retina.width/2)+'px '+(-zoom*top+sizes.retina.height/2)+'px'
});
```

Test this by checking that all four corners are seen correctly in the retina, i.e. when you're over the corner of the main image, the corner should be in the center of the retina circle.

The second problem is if you resize the browser the position calculations are out because the offset variable isn't updated for the new size. A simple way to do this is to put this as the first line of webpage.mousemove() so the offsets are updated every time:

```
var offset  = { left: webpage.offset().left, top: webpage.offset().top };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the top/left position click point of the zoomed image to highlight where you have clicked. What you will need to do is alter your top/left position based on whether the fisheye is over the image or not.

Does the un-zoomed image have to be part of the news page or can it be a standalone image?

If it can be standalone then the solution should be quite simple. If the zoomed in image is twice the size of the unzoomed one then you can just set the top/left values of the highlight to half the value of the zoomed, when looking at the unzoomed.

Jquery position will allow you to accurately get the position.

[jQuery Position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: Thanks James, to how much do I alter the top/left based on the fisheye? Thats the issue I am having. It doesn't have to be part of it, if you look at my original demo, I am just trying to add a fish eye to that. Any ideas?